# Maven cannot find package of installed artifact

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm trying to run `mvn clean install` on a project and get a message after failure that says (names changed):

```
C:\<...>\SomeClass.java:[23,29] error: package org.example.codes does not exist
```

This error is shown for several packages, which all belong to the same project/artifact. But this artifact is installed, i.e. its jar and meta-stuff is inside `<user-dir>/.m2/repository` and when trying to install it again from command line, it says

```
Cannot install artifact. Artifact is already in the local repository.
```

I checked by hand (using WinRAR) and the structure inside this jar clearly looks like those "missing" packages are actually there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried `mvn -X clean install` to get debug output? also, it might be that versions don't match, I think you'd get the same error then.

Comment: I used it right now, but it throws a huge amount of output at me, but I can't see any more useful information in it... About the versions: It's a project I'm porting from one computer to the other, so project and (local) repository versions should match, I've just copied everything until now, trying to modify as little as possible.

Comment: The message says that an import in your SomeClass java file does not exist. I would assume that you missed to add an dependency to your project or missing to clean up the import statements.

Comment: It's working now, but I cannot exactly say why. What I did was to re-copy the whole directory of the problem-project (inside "repository"), so there must have been some problems when copying... I'm confused.